# Prevent exiting FullScreen mode when using text input inside an Android WebView?

Tags: javascript, android, webview, android-fullscreen

I'm making a fullscreen Android app.
Inside it I have a WebView that loads a web page that has a text input on it.
When user clicks on the text input the app exits the fullscreen mode and never returns back.

I can use a js-android interface to call a function that forces it to go back fullscreen every time the input loses the focus or make a fake on-screen keyboard but I'm looking for a better solution.

This is how I force it to go into a fullscreen mode in the first place:

```
public static void setStickFullScreen(View view) {
    int systemUiVisibility = view.getSystemUiVisibility();
    int flags = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION 
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN 
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;
    systemUiVisibility |= flags;
    view.setSystemUiVisibility(systemUiVisibility);
}

@Override public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    setStickFullScreen(getWindow().getDecorView());
}
```

I want it to be always fullscreen without showing top and bottom android navigation.

Is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was in another place.

The theme of the app should've been inherited from the NoActionBar theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
...
</style>
```